# NextJs -> ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, vercel

So I just upgraded from Next v12 to v12.2.3, created a new middleware.js file in the root directory, tried to do a "yarn dev" and got this:

```
ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration[0].module.rules[5] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration[0].module.rules[5].include[0] has an unknown property 'pages'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[0].module.rules[5].include[0] has an unknown property 'appDir'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[0].module.rules[5].include[0] has an unknown property 'pages'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[0].module.rules[5].include[0] has an unknown property 'appDir'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
 - configuration[1].module.rules[4] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration[1].module.rules[4].include[0] has an unknown property 'pages'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[1].module.rules[4].include[0] has an unknown property 'appDir'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[1].module.rules[4].include[0] has an unknown property 'pages'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[1].module.rules[4].include[0] has an unknown property 'appDir'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
 - configuration[2].module.rules[8] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration[2].module.rules[8].include[0] has an unknown property 'pages'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[2].module.rules[8].include[0] has an unknown property 'appDir'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[2].module.rules[8].include[0] has an unknown property 'pages'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    * configuration[2].module.rules[8].include[0] has an unknown property 'appDir'. These properties are valid:
      object { and?, not?, or? }
      -> Logic operators used in a condition matcher.
    at validate (D:\GitHub\My_Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\schema-utils3\index.js:1:150815)
    at validateSchema (D:\GitHub\My_Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:139253:2)
    at create (D:\GitHub\My_Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:142750:24)
    at webpack (D:\GitHub\My_Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:142797:32)
    at Object.f [as webpack] (D:\GitHub\My_Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:97275:16)
    at HotReloader.start (D:\GitHub\My_Projects\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader.js:430:45)
    at async DevServer.prepare (D:\GitHub\My_Project\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:334:9)
    at async D:\GitHub\My_Project\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:147:9 {
  errors: [
    {
      keyword: 'oneOf',
      dataPath: '[0].module.rules',
      schemaPath: '#/properties/rules/oneOf',
      params: [Object],
      message: 'should match exactly one schema in oneOf',
      schema: [Array],
      parentSchema: [Object],
      data: [Array],
      children: [Array]
    },
    {
      keyword: 'oneOf',
      dataPath: '[1].module.rules',
      schemaPath: '#/properties/rules/oneOf',
      params: [Object],
      message: 'should match exactly one schema in oneOf',
      schema: [Array],
      parentSchema: [Object],
      data: [Array],
      children: [Array]
    },
    {
      keyword: 'oneOf',
      dataPath: '[2].module.rules',
      schemaPath: '#/properties/rules/oneOf',
      params: [Object],
      message: 'should match exactly one schema in oneOf',
      schema: [Array],
      parentSchema: [Object],
      data: [Array],
      children: [Array]
    }
  ],
  schema: {
    definitions: {
      Amd: [Object],
      AssetFilterItemTypes: [Object],
      AssetFilterTypes: [Object],
      AssetGeneratorDataUrl: [Object],
      AssetGeneratorDataUrlFunction: [Object],
      AssetGeneratorDataUrlOptions: [Object],
      AssetGeneratorOptions: [Object],
      AssetInlineGeneratorOptions: [Object],
      AssetModuleFilename: [Object],
      AssetModuleOutputPath: [Object],
      AssetParserDataUrlFunction: [Object],
      AssetParserDataUrlOptions: [Object],
      AssetParserOptions: [Object],
      AssetResourceGeneratorOptions: [Object],
      AuxiliaryComment: [Object],
      Bail: [Object],
      CacheOptions: [Object],
      CacheOptionsNormalized: [Object],
      Charset: [Object],
      ChunkFilename: [Object],
      ChunkFormat: [Object],
      ChunkLoadTimeout: [Object],
      ChunkLoading: [Object],
      ChunkLoadingGlobal: [Object],
      ChunkLoadingType: [Object],
      Clean: [Object],
      CleanOptions: [Object],
      CompareBeforeEmit: [Object],
      Context: [Object],
      CrossOriginLoading: [Object],
      CssChunkFilename: [Object],
      CssExperimentOptions: [Object],
      CssFilename: [Object],
      CssGeneratorOptions: [Object],
      CssParserOptions: [Object],
      Dependencies: [Object],
      DevServer: [Object],
      DevTool: [Object],
      DevtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: [Object],
      DevtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: [Object],
      DevtoolNamespace: [Object],
      EmptyGeneratorOptions: [Object],
      EmptyParserOptions: [Object],
      EnabledChunkLoadingTypes: [Object],
      EnabledLibraryTypes: [Object],
      EnabledWasmLoadingTypes: [Object],
      Entry: [Object],
      EntryDescription: [Object],
      EntryDescriptionNormalized: [Object],
      EntryDynamic: [Object],
      EntryDynamicNormalized: [Object],
      EntryFilename: [Object],
      EntryItem: [Object],
      EntryNormalized: [Object],
      EntryObject: [Object],
      EntryRuntime: [Object],
      EntryStatic: [Object],
      EntryStaticNormalized: [Object],
      EntryUnnamed: [Object],
      Environment: [Object],
      Experiments: [Object],
      ExperimentsCommon: [Object],
      ExperimentsNormalized: [Object],
      ExternalItem: [Object],
      ExternalItemFunctionData: [Object],
      ExternalItemValue: [Object],
      Externals: [Object],
      ExternalsPresets: [Object],
      ExternalsType: [Object],
      FileCacheOptions: [Object],
      Filename: [Object],
      FilenameTemplate: [Object],
      FilterItemTypes: [Object],
      FilterTypes: [Object],
      GeneratorOptionsByModuleType: [Object],
      GlobalObject: [Object],
      HashDigest: [Object],
      HashDigestLength: [Object],
      HashFunction: [Object],
      HashSalt: [Object],
      HotUpdateChunkFilename: [Object],
      HotUpdateGlobal: [Object],
      HotUpdateMainFilename: [Object],
      HttpUriAllowedUris: [Object],
      HttpUriOptions: [Object],
      HttpUriOptionsAllowedUris: [Object],
      IgnoreWarnings: [Object],
      IgnoreWarningsNormalized: [Object],
      Iife: [Object],
      ImportFunctionName: [Object],
      ImportMetaName: [Object],
      InfrastructureLogging: [Object],
      JavascriptParserOptions: [Object],
      Layer: [Object],
      LazyCompilationDefaultBackendOptions: [Object],
      LazyCompilationOptions: [Object],
      Library: [Object],
      LibraryCustomUmdCommentObject: [Object],
      LibraryCustomUmdObject: [Object],
      LibraryExport: [Object],
      LibraryName: [Object],
      LibraryOptions: [Object],
      LibraryType: [Object],
      Loader: [Object],
      MemoryCacheOptions: [Object],
      Mode: [Object],
      ModuleFilterItemTypes: [Object],
      ModuleFilterTypes: [Object],
      ModuleOptions: [Object],
      ModuleOptionsNormalized: [Object],
      Name: [Object],
      NoParse: [Object],
      Node: [Object],
      NodeOptions: [Object],
      Optimization: [Object],
      OptimizationRuntimeChunk: [Object],
      OptimizationRuntimeChunkNormalized: [Object],
      OptimizationSplitChunksCacheGroup: [Object],
      OptimizationSplitChunksGetCacheGroups: [Object],
      OptimizationSplitChunksOptions: [Object],
      OptimizationSplitChunksSizes: [Object],
      Output: [Object],
      OutputModule: [Object],
      OutputNormalized: [Object],
      Parallelism: [Object],
      ParserOptionsByModuleType: [Object],
      Path: [Object],
      Pathinfo: [Object],
      Performance: [Object],
      PerformanceOptions: [Object],
      Plugins: [Object],
      Profile: [Object],
      PublicPath: [Object],
      RawPublicPath: [Object],
      RecordsInputPath: [Object],
      RecordsOutputPath: [Object],
      RecordsPath: [Object],
      Resolve: [Object],
      ResolveAlias: [Object],
      ResolveLoader: [Object],
      ResolveOptions: [Object],
      ResolvePluginInstance: [Object],
      RuleSetCondition: [Object],
      RuleSetConditionAbsolute: [Object],
      RuleSetConditionOrConditions: [Object],
      RuleSetConditionOrConditionsAbsolute: [Object],
      RuleSetConditions: [Object],
      RuleSetConditionsAbsolute: [Object],
      RuleSetLoader: [Object],
      RuleSetLoaderOptions: [Object],
      RuleSetLogicalConditions: [Object],
      RuleSetLogicalConditionsAbsolute: [Object],
      RuleSetRule: [Object],
      RuleSetRules: [Object],
      RuleSetUse: [Object],
      RuleSetUseItem: [Object],
      ScriptType: [Object],
      SnapshotOptions: [Object],
      SourceMapFilename: [Object],
      SourcePrefix: [Object],
      StatsOptions: [Object],
      StatsValue: [Object],
      StrictModuleErrorHandling: [Object],
      StrictModuleExceptionHandling: [Object],
      Target: [Object],
      TrustedTypes: [Object],
      UmdNamedDefine: [Object],
      UniqueName: [Object],
      WarningFilterItemTypes: [Object],
      WarningFilterTypes: [Object],
      WasmLoading: [Object],
      WasmLoadingType: [Object],
      Watch: [Object],
      WatchOptions: [Object],
      WebassemblyModuleFilename: [Object],
      WebpackOptionsNormalized: [Object],
      WebpackPluginFunction: [Object],
      WebpackPluginInstance: [Object]
    },
    title: 'WebpackOptions',
    description: 'Options object as provided by the user.',
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
      amd: [Object],
      bail: [Object],
      cache: [Object],
      context: [Object],
      dependencies: [Object],
      devServer: [Object],
      devtool: [Object],
      entry: [Object],
      experiments: [Object],
      externals: [Object],
      externalsPresets: [Object],
      externalsType: [Object],
      ignoreWarnings: [Object],
      infrastructureLogging: [Object],
      loader: [Object],
      mode: [Object],
      module: [Object],
      name: [Object],
      node: [Object],
      optimization: [Object],
      output: [Object],
      parallelism: [Object],
      performance: [Object],
      plugins: [Object],
      profile: [Object],
      recordsInputPath: [Object],
      recordsOutputPath: [Object],
      recordsPath: [Object],
      resolve: [Object],
      resolveLoader: [Object],
      snapshot: [Object],
      stats: [Object],
      target: [Object],
      watch: [Object],
      watchOptions: [Object]
    }
  },
  headerName: 'Webpack',
  baseDataPath: 'configuration',
  postFormatter: [Function: postFormatter]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have no idea why this happened, what it means or how to fix it, but now I can't even revert to v12 and get anything to run!
I don't touch any webpack stuff, I don't have any webpack config files, so I'm not sure what to do.
Here is my next.config.js file:

```
    const { withSuperjson } = require('next-superjson')
    
    module.exports = withSuperjson()({
        images: {
            domains: [`${process.env.S3_UPLOAD_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com`],
            formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
        },
        eslint: {
            // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
            // your project has ESLint errors.
            ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
        },
    
    });
```

I've tried deleting .next folder, I've deleted node modules, I've reverted to a different branch and it still doesn't work! Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I've just updated `next-superjson` from 0.0.2 to 0.0.4 and it appears to run again, phew. I had updated `superjson`, but not `next-superjson` originally to no avail.